# Autolayout in tabs

Tags: swift, uiview, autolayout, uistackview

Tab Bar

[image: Tab Bar]

I want Chat image in between  that menu and people image and fire image in between menu and notification image using autolayout.

1. I have applied leading, center vertical, fix width and fix height o Chat image
2. For fire image I have given trailing and remaining same as chat image.

   **Note:** This is not tab bar this is custom view.

Above problem solved but now in iPhoneX am getting 
that bottom bar is hidden

How can i come out from this issue?

[image: iPhoneX SS]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a container with leading and trailing - 0 - to surrounding images(people and menu), and center horizontally the image (chat) inside this container.

or:

```
chat.center = CGPoint(menu.frame.minX - people.frame.maxX)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating view programatically then make sure buttons in view have aspect ratio with screen width.

Why don't you use Horizontal Stack View.

See below image

[image]

Comment: With stack view we can not create view as in image.

Comment: U can assign image to buttons right? elaborate your question

Comment: Yes i assigned image on buttons and applied constraints on them.